# How can I partition an Arrow Table by value in one pass?

Tags: apache-arrow

I would like to be able to partition an Arrow table by the values of one of its columns (assuming the set of *n* values occurring in that column is known). The straightforward way is a for-loop: for each of these values, scan the whole table and build a new table of matching rows. Are there ways to do this in one pass instead of *n* passes?

I initially thought that Arrow's  support for group-by scans would be the solution -- but Arrow (in contrast to Pandas) does not support extracting groups after a group-by scan.

Am I just thinking about this wrong and there is another way to partition a table in one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the group by support, there is a ["hash_list" function](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/bbf249e056315af0a18d5c0834de9adef117a25f/cpp/src/arrow/compute/kernels/hash_aggregate.cc#L2775-L2777) that returns all values in the group. Is that what you're looking for? You could then slice the resulting values after-the-fact to extract the individual groups.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for, @li.davidm -- I assumed aggregation always meant reduction and didn't realize that "list" was part of the grouped aggregate functions.

Comment: Where were you looking, in case we can update the docs? It's described here, though very briefly: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html?highlight=hash_list#grouped-aggregations-group-by